# How to keep the hover detected while holding a grabbable item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to create a VR mini game using Unity XR Interaction Toolkit. My issue is that my first object don't detect my hand hovering it anymore if this hand is currently holding a grabbable object.

I tried to find a boolean or anything that allow me to force to keep the hover event reacting to my hand even when I'm holding into an object, but without success.

Let's make it simple and show you how it's currently working VS how I want it to work :

1 - In game, go over an object called "A" using the "XR Simple Interactable" component that change it's material when hovered and return to default when not hovered anymore, as show in the picture bellow :
[image: A's Hover setting]

2 - Hover it and WOW it changed color ! You can stop hovering it.

3 - Now grab an object called "B" with the component "XR Grab Interactable" and hold it in your hand.

4 - With the hand holding "B", try to hover "A"

---

Expected result : "A" change color

Current result : "A" don't care about you

Thanks for your advices :)